# In Rails, how to translate buttons in javascript popup confirm box

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, confirm, rails-i18n

When including `data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }` to a [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) helper, how do we translate the two buttons "Cancel" and "OK" in the popup?

Is the Rail's I18n applicable in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default (relying on the `data-confirm` attribute and calling `window.confirm()`), rails-ujs uses the browser's native confirmation dialogs, so you can't really translate them, they will use the browser's translation.

If you use some alternative solution (which actually replaces the `data-confirm` attribute with something else) the views depend on the specific solution you choose (for example http://lesseverything.com/blog/archives/2012/07/18/customizing-confirmation-dialog-in-rails/)

TL;DR: You can't.